# Making drop down deactivate if one drop down is selected out of 3

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have 3 drop down lists , if a person selects from 1st dropdown the other two should be disabled. how to make that in asp.net using c#

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ajax control toolkit and use the [cascading dropdown control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in SelectedIndexChanged event of the DropDownList.
and enable AutoPostBack

Answer (score 0):

Click the little lightning bolt in the properties in visual studio, then double click the selectedindexchanged to get the event to show up in the code. Also enable autopostback in the properties. In the selectedindexchanged event, look for the selecteditem value and set the control to enabled = false. you may want to start with the 2nd two already disabled and enable them on the selectedindexchanged. also, add a value in the ddl before the other values so you can make sure they actually selected a value from the ddl rather than a title. (if not ddl1.selectedindex = 0 then ddl2.enabled = true)